# What happens to FGA when you score on the wrong basket?

Tags: rules, nba, scoring

I know that when you score on the wrong basket, the nearest player gets the points (in NBA) - so that's "Field Goal Made". But, what about "Field Goal Attempts"? If the nearest player doesn't have any attempts in this game, will it be 1/1 or 1/0?

Moreover, what about the unfortunate player that actually scored the "own FG"? Does his FGA increase? Is it a violation?

Comment: Most likely 0/0 and just two points added to the overall score of that player (and a footnote on the sheet)